# C# member parameter as expression and extract the string name

Tags: c#, expression, func

I want to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine( PrintMyName(x => x.EmailAddress) );


public class User{
   public string EmailAddress{get;set;}
}
```

Now the problem is, as seen bellow that `propertyInfo` is `null`.

```
public string PrintMyName(Func<T,object> member){
   var propertyInfo = (member.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
   return propertyInfo.Name;
}
```

What is the righte way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: `PrintMyName(Func<T,object> member)` should probably be `PrintMyName<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> member)`, and `PrintMyName(x => x.EmailAddress)` should probably be `PrintMyName<User>(x => x.EmailAddress`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be something like this:

```
    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (body != null)
        {
            return body.Member.Name;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

usage (use Tuple as an example):

```
var theName = GetPropertyName<Tuple<string>>(x => x.Item1);
```